# Termux autotools/libtool cannot determine link -lib interface

Tags: android, autotools, libtool, termux

I'm using Termux for Android 12. I've got a simple [C project](https://github.com/InnovAnon-Inc/test) using autotools. I run:

```
autoreconf -i
./configure
```

And it fails saying:

```
checking the archiver (link -lib) interface... unknown
configure: error: could not determine link -lib interface
```

In src/Makefile.am:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = main
main_SOURCES = main.c foo.h
main_LDADD = libfoo.la
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES = foo.c foo.h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need foo.h in `include_HEADERS` rather than `main_SOURCES`:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = main
main_SOURCES = main.c
include_HEADERS = foo.h
main_LDADD = libfoo.la
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES = foo.c foo.h
```